# Как отправить фото через телеграмм бота?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, photo

Есть файл photos.py, в нем хранятся названия фото.

- `PHOTOS =` `["Абакан.jpg",` `"Абдулино.jpg",`
  `"Абинск.jpg",` `"Агидель.svg",` `"Агрыз.jpg",`
  `"Адыгейск.jpg",` `"Азнакаево.png",` `"Азов.jpg",`
  `"Ак-Довурак.png",` `"Алагир.jpg",` `"Алапаевск.jpg"]`
  В этом массиве не все названия фото.

Есть файл town.py, в нем хранятся города России.

- `towns = ["Абаза",` `"Абакан",` `"Абдулино",`
  `"Абинск",` `"Агидель",` `"Агрыз"]` В этом списке не все города.

Как сделать так, чтобы, когда пользователь вводил город, то отправлялось фото этого города.
Есть также папка photos_qwerty, в ней хранятся фото.

````
def get_user_text(message):
    with io.open('towns_for_bot.py', encoding='utf-8') as file_towns:
        with io.open('photos.py') as file_photos:
            if message.text in file_towns.read():
                photo_name = f'{message.text}.jpg'
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'AMOGUS POKUS')
                bot.send_media_group(message.chat.id, [telebot.types.InputMediaPhoto(open(f'{message.text}.jpg', 'rb'))])
            else:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Такого города нет")```
````

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте данный вариант:

```
from towns import towns
from photos import PHOTOS # Вы можете просто импоритировать переменые из ваших файлов .py
def get_user_text(message):
    for p in PHOTOS:
        for t in towns:
            if p.startswinth(t):
                with open(f"photos_qwerty\\{p}", "rb") as photo: 
                    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo)
                break
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Такого города нет")
```